# What is the difference between including iostream and including iostream.h?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between iostream and iostream.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976477/difference-between-iostream-and-iostream-h)

My professor said that the following:

```
#include <iostream.h>
```

is the same as:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

I'm a bit confused. What is the difference between `iostream` and `iostream.h`?

Comment: `iostream.h` isn't real.

Comment: Your professor needs to get out of 1988 and join the rest of us.

Comment: Many of the standard C header files (such as `<stdio.h>`) have a C++ equivalent (such as `<cstdio>`) which wraps the C functions in `namespace std`, but `iostream` is not one of them.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: The famous `ciostream`

Comment: To be crystal clear on this point: **your professor is wrong**. Might be worth pondering on what else he's been wrong about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`iostream.h` is not part of the standard C++ library whereas `iostream` is. Names in `iostream.h` are not in the `std` namespace, whereas those in `iostream` are. By issuing the directive `using namespace std` after including `iostream`, all names defined there (and in any other standard library includes) are brought into the global namespace. That is usually not a good thing, but it does provide some level of equivalence between the standard and non- or pre-standard versions.

As far as claiming that they are "the same" as each other, this is unlikely. `iostream` adheres to the standard, and will have evolved w.r.t. `iostream.h`. This is particularly true if you consider the C++11 standard.

Answer (score 1):

Some very old compilers have used `iostream.h`, but it's not part of the standard. Only the extensionless header files are. It won't even be recognized by modern standard-compliant compilers.