# iostream.h: no such file or directory

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I am using Windows 8.1 and Dev C++ and I have the following code:

```
#include<iostream.h>
main()
{
    cout<<"welcome to devc++";
    system("pause");    
}
```

The syntax is correct, but I get an error that says:

> [Error] iostream.h: No such file or directory

I have tried to change to location of this .cpp folder, watched video tutorials, but I could not point out why I am getting this error and how to remove it.

Comment: Use only `iostream` and it should be `int main()`.

Comment: I think you're using Orwell Dev-C++.  It comes in two flavours, with and without compiler suite.  If you're using the latter, you've to manually set up the compiler.  If you're unsure, you should use the package that comes with the compiler. All this if you face the error even after switching to `<iostream>`.

Comment: You may want to read a modern book on C++. iostream.h went obsolete some 18 years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to changing to

```
#include <iostream>
```

You can also add

```
using namespace std;
```

before main if you want to use `cout` without having to use `std::cout`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `#include<iostream>` instead of `#include<iostream.h>`. The later one has been deprecated now; which is why you face the error.  More details [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976477/difference-between-iostream-and-iostream-h).

Besides, `main()` being a function, should have a return type.  So, you should write `int main()` and not just `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

**Just do**,

```
#include <iostream>
```

instead of

```
#include <iostream.h>
```

because, as `C++`  progressed from specific implementation to standard one,`.h` were deprecated from he library.