# Iostream in Borland C++ compiler

Tags: c++, dos, iostream

In my old computer (nearly 15years), I use MsDos and Borland C++ compiler.
The problem is,

```
#include <iostream.h>
```

works but

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std
```

This doesn't works here.

Is there any way to use modern IDE on MsDos

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is your question?

Comment: This was covered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976477/difference-between-iostream-and-iostream-h

Comment: Don’t use such an old compiler. Or if you have to don’t expect anything relevant to C++ these days to work with it

Comment: @ggorlen how can I run that in Boreland C++

Comment: @RandytheDev that's not my problem, I am not asking the difference b/w them

Comment: @Joe is there any other compiler for dos?

Comment: @UjjwalSingh if your goal is to write modern C++ in Borland you can’t. It supports a very old pre-standard-library version of the language. Use a different compiler or write code suitable for the compiler.

Comment: If you want to use Borland, that's great, but this lack of support for `<iostream>` is a harbinger of things to come. You are basically not going to be able to reference much of anything from the past 20 years and expect it to work.

Comment: The problem is I switched my Operating system to Puppy linux but it was still lagging, So I returned to MsDos

Comment: What is wrong with just using `#include <iostream.h>`???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Borland is so old that it was made before the C++ Standard Library existed.

At that time the effective standard for C++ was the ARM, the Annotated Reference Manual by Bjarne Stroustrup and Margaret Ellis, and it was named `<iostream.h>`.

With the first standardisation in 1998 `<iostream.h>` was dropped, and replaced with just `<iostream>`.

I don't know what to say. Just use `<iostream.h>`, or a newer compiler.

Comment: It means I have to change my operating system

Comment: Or just use `#include <iostream.h>`...

Comment: @Ujjwal Singh You could use [DJGPP](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/) which runs in DOS. But be aware that this is only a compiler and not a fully fledged IDE like Borland C++ 3.1

Comment: @Swordfish RHIDE is an IDE for DJGPP.

Comment: @BernhardEriksson nice! :)