# Did the namespaces exist prior to the introduction of the C++ 98 standard?

Tags: c++, namespaces, c++98

I read this page.
[C++ header files with no extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40624930/c-header-files-with-no-extension#comment68502179_40628360)
And I understood that comment as saying that namespaces existed even before the introduction of the C++ standard.
So wasn't that comment saying that namespaces and the absence of file extension are not related?
However, the following comment didn't mention how namespaces were used when using `cout` in iostream.h.

So my Questions are:

1. Did the namespace really exist prior to the introduction of the C++ 98 standard?
2. If it is true, how namespaces were used when using `cout` in iostream.h?

Comment: There wasn't a standard... so it is kind of like chicken and egg situation. I know that the Watcom C++ compiler had namespace support from version 9.5 on (first version with C++ / 1994), even though I started using that in 1996. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watcom_C/C%2B%2B)

Comment: Also see : [iostream-in-borland-c-compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51434007/iostream-in-borland-c-compiler)

Comment: C++ did not begin the journey toward standardization until the early 90s. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/history

Comment: @molbdnilo I see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The committee voted to accept namespaces into the standard in 1993. Most compilers supported it fairly shortly after that, so for around 5 years before the standard was approved.

Headers without extensions happened around the same time, so mostly when you used `iostream.h`, you just used `cout << foo;`, and when you switched to `iostream`, you used `std::cout << foo;`.

For backward compatibility, many compilers continued to supply an `iostream.h` for a while after they had `iostream`. It was often something like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

This was enough for a lot of fairly simple programs to compile, but broke with some that got into the dark corners of the older library code (and honestly, not even very dark corners).

Other compilers had two completely separate libraries though, so `iostream.h` contained declarations for one and `iostream` for the other.

Answer (score 1):

namespace concept was introduced to C++ in the 90s but the features and syntax were refined in C++98 standard

note that `iostream.h` header file isn't part of the C++ standard library -- it was used by early versions of Borland compiler for MS-DOS and has been deprecated for the standard `<iostream>` header

`cout` object is defined in the `std` namespace in the standard `<iostream>` header => that's why to use it you have to either:

- qualify with prefix

```
std::cout
```

- or bring the std namespace into scope

```
namespace std;
```

Comment: Re: "used by early versions of Borland compiler" -- literally true, but misleading; `<iostream.h>` came from Cfront, the original Bell Labs implementation of C++. And, formally, `<iostream.h>` was not deprecated; it never existed in the C++ standard. "Deprecated" means that something is supported in the current version of the standard, but might be removed in the future.